# gRPC порт подключения на сервере

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5

Можно ли изменить порт для подключения по gRPC со стандартного 5001 на какой-нибудь другой свободный со стороны сервера? Да, я понимаю, что тогда и клиент должен будет знать этот порт. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Да, можно......

Comment: @aepot а можете, пожалуйста, показать по коду? На клиенте-то понятно, как это сделать, но как на сервере - пока что не понимаю.

Comment: gRPC работает через HTTPS, меняете порт HTTPS и готово. Как это сделать - зависит от сервера, который вы используете IIS, Kestrel и т.д. Настройка в конфигах этого сервера.

Comment: @aepot делал по примеру отсюда: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio (стандартный проект gRPC).
Но не совсем понимаю, как все-таки это дело правильно настроить. CreateHostBuilder сейчас выглядит вот так:
`public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });`

Comment: appsettings.json https://stackoverflow.com/a/37365382/12888024